# Highchart Area Tooltip not showing all elements

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I'm using highchart js for drawing charts. But, I have a problem with the Highchart area Tooltip not showing all elements (it's showing n-1 elements). I opened the Inspector in Google Chrome, showing all elements (code not changing). I'm confused as to why this is occurring:

[image: highchart with all elements in tooltip]

[image: highchart not showing all elements in tooltip]

Comment: Could you please post live example of your chart, so we can investigate what may cause your issue?

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve